# Wrapper for boolean type to reduce the use of if statements

Tags: java

I want to create wrapper for boolean type to not use more if statements. Can you tell me that this class make sense?

```
public final class Bool {

    private boolean value;

    private Bool(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static final Bool of(boolean value) {
        return new Bool(value);
    }

    public static final Bool ofFalse() {
        return new Bool(false);
    }

    public static final Bool ofTrue() {
        return new Bool(true);
    }

    public OrElse ifTrue(Procedure procedure) {
        if (value)
            procedure.invoke();
        return new OrElse(!value);
    }

    public OrElse ifFalse(Procedure procedure) {
        if (!value)
            procedure.invoke();
       return new OrElse(value);
    }

    public class OrElse {
        private boolean value;

        private OrElse(boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void orElse(Procedure procedure) {
            if (value)
                procedure.invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
public Bool findElement(String name) {
    for(Element el : elements) {
       if(el.getName().equals(name)) return Bool.ofTrue();
    }
    return Bool.ofFalse();
}


// And now in other place of code I may use:
findElement("el").ifTrue(() -> doSomething).orElse(() -> doSomethingElse)
```

Comment: Is this for production code or just for fun (your motivation is important to answer the question; If it's just for fun, people can focus on design, etc; if it's for production, you should expand on your explanation, otherwise people will just tell you not to do this (performance, readability, etc.))? And can you also post `Procedure`? And maybe a usage example or unit tests? It would help readers of your question to understand what your code tries to achieve.

Comment: This is for production code. Procedure is my own functional interface which takes no arguments and return no result.

Answer (score 3):

**Approach**

The approach is interesting, but doesn't seem practical or actually useful.

I think that you need more justification for this than simply stating that you want to use less if-statements.

Especially since you essentially still have the if-structure, just with a different syntax:

```
// your code:
findElement("el").ifTrue(() -> doSomething).orElse(() -> doSomethingElse)

// regular if, one line (which I would not recommend, it's more difficult to read than multi-line):
if (findElement("el")) doSomething; else doSomethingElse;

// standard if:
if (findElement("el")) {
    doSomething;
} else {
    doSomethingElse;
}
```

If there are other reasons for your approach, you need to make them clear. But this is definitely not a good replacement for general-purpose if statements.

And if you use this throughout a project, you have dependencies to this custom wrapper everywhere. Removing it later will be a lot of work. You will also need to wrap each return value from libraries and the standard APIs (which will be ugly in itself), or your code will consist of a mixture of standard ifs and your approach, which will not help readability.

**Readability**

Your approach is already more difficult to read than the standard approach, and with anything except a simple function-call, your approach would be even less readable:

```
// your code:
findElement("el").ifTrue(() -> {doSomething; doSomething2; doSomething3;}).orElse(() -> doSomethingElse; doSomethingElse2;)

// standard:
if (findElement("el")) {
    doSomething;
    doSomething2; 
    doSomething3;
} else {
    doSomethingElse;
    doSomethingElse2;
}
```

You can of course also make your version multi-line, but that doesn't make matters much better:

```
findElement("el").ifTrue(() -> {
    doSomething; 
    doSomething2; 
    doSomething3;
}).orElse(() -> {
    doSomethingElse; 
    doSomethingElse2;
})
```

You are still recreating the if-structure, just with a worse syntax.

**Performance**

I did not profile your approach, but in many situations, the extra cost of the additional function calls for the simplest of basic expressions will be noticeable.

**Misc**

- I would recommend curly brackets even for one-line statements. They do make code easier to read, and can prevent bugs.
- I would always use `this` when accessing fields, it makes it clearer where values come from.
- Do you really need the `value` field and `if` in `OrElse`? I would assume that an else should always be executed.